# Storing ASP.NET MVC4 SimpleMembership data in Table Storage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-table-storage

I want to store all SimpleMembership provider data within Azure Table Storage. 
Is there any complete guides to implement this functionality?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Arran requirements...

Answer (score 1):

There's a project on CodePlex called AzureProviders

http://azureproviders.codeplex.com/

It provides TableStorage & BlobStorage backed, Membership & Role provider implementations.

Comment: Does it suits to SimpleMembership?